# Grails custom class mapping for table-per-hierarchy domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Grails creates a `class` column in the database for a table-per-hierarchy mapping and uses full class name for its typed queries. So a saved instance of a domain class `class Volvo extends Car` in package `com.example` will generate a `com.example.Volvo` entry in the `class` column of the `Car` table. This obviously limits package refactoring or reusing pre-existing value sets from legacy databases. 
Is it possible to use custom class mapping for a table-per-hierarchy domain class strategy? For example, to map `com.example.Volvo` domain class to always generate a `VOLVO` value in the `Car`'s `class` table?

Comment: How often do you refactor your class packages? Isn't it easier just to update all `class` rows in the table?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc That's what I have been doing. But the question is broader - how can I control superfluous package information in the database generated by Grails. I may have a legacy database with a fixed item type column with a fixed set of values. Can I perhaps rename that column to class and make typed queries against it without having to put packages everywhere?